# split в ant

Tags: ant, java

Пишу build для ant. 
Нужно копировать файлы перечисленные в файле property, т.е. их нужно перечислить в include. Но если в include передать переменную из пропертей, к примеру:

```
include name=${fileset.include}
```

то в результате получится что то вроде

```
<include name="**/*.pom, **/*property"/>
```

, соответственно так не срабатывает.

Хотелось бы узнать как это обойти, т.е. есть ли в ant'e что то вроде split?

Comment: можно нескромный вопрос зачем вам писать ant скрипт для работы с maven? :)

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял суть вопроса, но вроде бы это то что нужно.
В папке с существующим `java` проэктом создал папку 'targetdir' и два файла

list.property :

```
**/*.txt
**/*.java
```

build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="project" default="default">
    <target name="default">
        <copy todir="targetdir">
            <fileset dir="." includesfile="list.property" />
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

Результат, - все `java` и `txt` файлы скопированы в `targetdir`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
<fileset dir="mydir">     
   <include name="**/*.pom"/>     
   <include name="**/*.property"/>   
</fileset>
```

Или

```
<fileset dir="mydir">     
   <include name="**/*.pom"/>     
</fileset> 
<fileset dir="mydir">     
   <include name="**/*.property"/>   
</fileset>
```